# Getting backslash(\) along with aphostrophe(') when I send the Push Notification message using PHP

Tags: php, html, ios, regex

I have a PHP script for sending push notification message to phones. We are able to send and receive the normal messages perfectly. But when I use aphostrophe(') in the message, we are not able to receive messages in the phones. After googling it out I have found one function in PHP [addslashes($variable_name)]. Now when i use this function, we are receiving the messages but not like it is intended so, meaning I am getting "\" where ever there is aphostrophe (') in a notification message.

For example, 
1)  Hello Everyone !!!     - When I send this message, we are able to get the push notification message.

2) come on Let's Play the game !!! - When I  send this message, first of all, we are not able to get the message, but when I use the php function [addslashes()] then we get the message but not correctly, 
We get the message like this - come on Let\'s Play the game (notice that there is a backslash() before aphostrope(') (Let\'s)), which is not the correct message.

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks in advance!!!

My PHP Code:

```
     $msg = $_POST['messageTxt'];    // Gets the Notification Message from the User
     $message = addslashes($msg);
    $device_token ="************************************************************";
      $device = $device_token;
                $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $message, 'badge' => +1, 'sound' => 'default');
                $payload = json_encode($payload);


                $options = array('ssl' => array(
                'local_cert' =>'****',
                'passphrase' => '*****'
                ));
                        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                       //                      APNS SERVER CONNECTIVITY                               //
                      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                $streamContext = stream_context_create();
                stream_context_set_option($streamContext, $options);
                $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

                $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $device)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;

               //  echo $apnsMessage.'<br> <br>';

                $res=fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);

                $payload ='';
                $apnsMessage='';
 fclose($apns);  // Closes the APNS Sercer Connection
```

Comment: why negative mark for this???????????

Answer (score 1):

Though I have no specific experience with push messages, I would try to solve json coding-decoding problems with json "native" encoding options, no php `addslashes()` or whatsoever.
Try `json_encode()` options, particularly:

```
json_encode($payload, JSON_HEX_QUOT);
```

I would also test for other possible issues with other special chars (<, >, &, etc...) and test corresponding `json_encode()` options.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php (see param `int $options = 0`)
http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php (see JSON_HEX_QUOT, JSON_HEX_TAG, JSON_HEX_AMP, JSON_HEX_APOS, *and maybe JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES combined with `addslashes()`* )

Comment: Thanks for the reply,, I will look into it.;)